# JavaScript: Close WebSocket when server goes offline

Tags: javascript, websocket

I'm using WebSockets to communicate between an ESP8266 (server, using the [arduinoWebSockets library](https://github.com/Links2004/arduinoWebSockets)) and JavaScript running on a web page (client).

I'd like to notify the user when the connection between the ESP and the browser is lost.
To check if the connection still works, the client sends a "p" message every second, and the server just echoes it. If it the client doesn't receive this echo within a second, it closes the connection (`WS.close();`).
The `WS.onclose` event sets a timeout to establish a new connection.

This approach works, but the problem is that when the internet connection is lost, or when the server resets, `WS.close()` doesn't work as expected.
It just spends 60 seconds in the `WebSocket.CLOSING` state, and then times out, calling the `onclose` event one minute too late.

Is there a way to immediately disconnect the WebSocket connection when the server is offline?

```
let WS;
let WStimeout;
let pingInterval;

startWS();

function startWS() {
    console.log("Start WebSocket");
    WS = new WebSocket('ws://' + location.hostname + ':81/');
    WS.onopen = function () {
        pingInterval = setInterval(ping, 1000);
    };
    WS.onerror = function (err) {
        console.log('WebSocket Error ', err);
    };
    WS.onclose = function (ev) {
        console.log("WebSocket Closed ", ev);
        clearInterval(pingInterval);
        // ... let user know that the connection is lost
        WS = null;  // delete the current WebSocket
        setTimeout(startWS, 5000);  // try connecting to WebSocket server again in 5 seconds
    }
    WS.onmessage = function (ev) {
        clearTimeout(WStimeout);  // server is still online, clear "ping" timeout
        console.log(ev.data);
        // ... handle incoming data
    }
}

function ping() {
    if (!WS || WS.readyState !== WebSocket.OPEN) {
        console.log("Connection not open: " + WS.readyState);
        return;
    }
    WS.send("p");  // send ping to server
    WStimeout = setTimeout(function () {  // if it doesn't respond within a second
        if (WS && WS.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {  // and if the connection is still open
            console.error("Ping timed out: closing WebSocket connection ...");
            WS.close();  // close the connection
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Output:

```
Start WebSocket
p
...
p

* Turned WiFi off and on again *

Ping timed out: closing WebSocket connection ...

Connection not open: 2
... (60 times in total, for 1 minute)
Connection not open: 2

WebSocket Closed  
CloseEvent {isTrusted: true, wasClean: false, code: 1006, reason: "", type: "close", …}

Start WebSocket
p
...
```

Comment: Welcome to TCP ;D Can't you just start the timeout directly after you closed the connection (so at the point where you called `WS.close()` instead of in the `onclose` handler)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that does indeed work. Is it good practice to just use `WS = null` without calling `WS.close()`?

Comment: I would probably call `WS.close()` nonetheless, and just ignore the `onclose`. Setting it to `null` probably doesn't make much of a difference.

Comment: The problem is that now the server keeps the old connections open, and the client keeps opening new connections, eventually crashing the server.

Comment: Can't you do something similar on the server side? Ping periodically and close the connection if the client seems to be gone.

Comment: That's what I'm currently implementing. It just seems weird that there's no standard way to do it. Isn't it a pretty normal thing to check if the connection is still open, and connect again if the connection fails?

Comment: The issue is that TCP is very resilient, and it typically takes hours before a connection is considered "broken". You could try and see if the TCP stack on the ESP8266 supports TCP keepalive, but that's only useful if you can set the initial timeout (on "real" OS'es it may take up to two hours before the first keepalive probes are being sent).